# PHP : Check topics and post´s - cleaner code

Tags: php, mysql

TL;DR:**Is there any better way to do this ? The code is kind of a mess but it works in my application**

id is the topic id and id2 is the reply id

```
$dn1 = mysql_query(
    'select c.id, c.name, c.description,c.position,c.bild,
    (
        select count(t.id)
        from topics as t
       where t.parent=c.id and t.id2=1
    ) as topics, 
    (
        select count(t2.id)
        from topics as t2
        where t2.parent=c.id and t2.id2!=1
    ) as replies 
    from categories as c
    group by c.id
    order by c.position asc'
);
$nb_cats = mysql_num_rows($dn1);
while($dnn1 = mysql_fetch_array($dn1)
```

Comment: Please, _please_, ***please*** STOP using the **deprecated** `mysql_*` extension! [read ***the red warning box*** in the man](http://php.net/mysql_connect). Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. Your code will emit `E_DEPRECATED` notices on php 5.5 and up. this was announced [over ***2 years ago***](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)

Comment: What is the desired behavior and the specific problem or error?

Comment: The Problem is that the code is a mess , I use 2 select statements inside of a select statement , that´s why I asked if there is any better way on the code side to get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, your query seems equivalent with this:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.description, c.position, c.bild,
    count(t1.id) as topics, count(t2.id) as replies
from categories as c
    inner join topics as t1 on t1.parent = c.id and t1.id2 = 1
    inner join topics as t2 on t2.parent = c.id and t2.id2 != 1
group by c.id
order by c.position asc
```

And I think the MySQL query planner has a similar opinion about it.

You can move the conditions involving `id2` field into a `WHERE` clause if you think it become more readable this way.

This query will return only the categories that have at least one topic and at least one response. If you also need the categories without topics or responses then you have to replace both `INNER JOIN`s with `LEFT JOIN`s and **keep** the conditions on `id2` where they are now.

Comment: This worked fine.I use left join cause I want to display categories without replies yet.I would like to expand it further that some categories are only for some users.I tried 

select c.id, c.name, c.description, c.position,c.rang,
    count(t1.id) as topics, count(t2.id) as replies
    from categories as c

    left join topics as t1 on t1.parent = c.id and t1.id2 = 1
    left join topics as t2 on t2.parent = c.id and t2.id2 != 1
    left join users as u on u.rang > c.rang and u.full_name ="'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'"

    group by c.id
    order by c.position asc');
But its not working

Comment: If you want to display specific results for each logged in user then you should keep the entire row of the current user in the session (or load it on each page load, after you checked that the user is logged in). Then you just pick the information from the user profile you need and put it into the query without joining the `users` table. Put any condition that is not a join condition into the [`WHERE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) clause. The `ON` should contain only the conditions that tells MySQL how to match the rows from the two joined tables.

Comment: I thought about that yesteday , but I didnt know if its more "efficient". Right now I just load the user_id and username into every page if u are logged in, so I thought myself, does it influence the speed "a lot" if I load the user rang on every page or is it better to do the querry when I need it

Comment: Having the user information cached in session allows you to check their properties without issuing queries on the `users` table to the database and to use their properties in other queries without joining the `users` table (less tables in a query => query runs faster). Most of the user properties (password, "rang" a.s.o.) change very seldom; it's a waste of resources to read them again and again from the DB. You have to be careful and discard the cached copy (load the data again from the DB) when they change but this happen only in a limited number of places (the "My profile" page, probably).

Comment: It influences the speed "a lot" when you have several hundred users online simultaneously. It's the difference between a site that responds (faster or slower but responds) and a site that times out waiting for the overloaded database to respond.

Comment: Thanks I get your points , in the seldom case that a user rang is changed I  just use the log out function and a message " please login again".  And well even if I dont expect a houndres of users its better to do the more efficient way.